# How to search groups of 3 lines with a certain pattern?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

What I want to do is simply search and print groups of 3 consecutive lines in the following file:

```
C30                1.86494717          7.48500210          9.88662475
O86                1.23405589          6.84423578         21.24967645
O88                5.28196032          8.12576842         21.24967645
O90                3.01950053          8.12576842          3.03566806
C32                8.01630633          7.48500210         15.95796089
O92                1.07505084          8.12576842          9.10700419
O94                7.22641001          8.12576842         15.17834032
O96                6.07185664          6.20346947         22.02929701
xxx                xxxxxxxxxx          xxxxxxxxxx         xxxxxxxxxxx
O111               3.82376560          6.83952632         25.21182108
H29                3.45376598          7.57952642         25.95182118
H30                4.93376561          6.83952632         25.21182108
O112               2.46658853          6.91893543         28.05848681
H31                2.09658891          7.65893553         28.79848692
H32                3.57658854          6.91893543         28.05848681
O113               6.25457469          6.74244996         26.28735053
H33                5.88457507          7.48245006         27.02735064
H34                7.36457470          6.74244996         26.28735053
```

I want to find in this case the lines which follow this pattern "O" "H" "H":

```
    Ox               
    Hx  
    Hx
```

I tried something with `grep` but it didn't work properly.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand what you want this sed should work

```
sed '/^O/{N;/\nH/{N;/\nH[^\n]*$/p}};d' file

O111               3.82376560          6.83952632         25.21182108
H29                3.45376598          7.57952642         25.95182118
H30                4.93376561          6.83952632         25.21182108
O112               2.46658853          6.91893543         28.05848681
H31                2.09658891          7.65893553         28.79848692
H32                3.57658854          6.91893543         28.05848681
O113               6.25457469          6.74244996         26.28735053
H33                5.88457507          7.48245006         27.02735064
H34                7.36457470          6.74244996         26.28735053
```

Edit

I messed up the above won't work if there is a multiple of two `O` lines together.

Below will though although its quite a bit longer...

```
sed '/^O/{:1;N;/\nH/{N;/\nH[^\n]*$/p};/\nO[^\n]*/{s/.*\n//;b1}};d' file
```

Comment: @git It will work if say there are three lines of Os's but not two, try it with just two lines of O's then the HH

Comment: It doesn't matter, for me work and it is all I need. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi again, do you know anything to select the inverse, I mean all except these 3 lines pattern...

Comment: @git Bit late, but just switch the `p` to `d` and remove the `d` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Using newer version of GNU `grep` having `-z` option to match multiline inputs :

```
$ grep -Pzo 'O[^\n]+\nH[^\n]+\nH[^\n]+' file.txt
O111               3.82376560          6.83952632         25.21182108
H29                3.45376598          7.57952642         25.95182118
H30                4.93376561          6.83952632         25.21182108
O112               2.46658853          6.91893543         28.05848681
H31                2.09658891          7.65893553         28.79848692
H32                3.57658854          6.91893543         28.05848681
O113               6.25457469          6.74244996         26.28735053
H33                5.88457507          7.48245006         27.02735064
H34                7.36457470          6.74244996         26.28735053
```

You can also use the `-M` option of `pcregrep` to match multiline inputs :

```
$ pcregrep -M 'O[^\n]+\nH[^\n]+\nH[^\n]+' file.txt 
O111               3.82376560          6.83952632         25.21182108
H29                3.45376598          7.57952642         25.95182118
H30                4.93376561          6.83952632         25.21182108
O112               2.46658853          6.91893543         28.05848681
H31                2.09658891          7.65893553         28.79848692
H32                3.57658854          6.91893543         28.05848681
O113               6.25457469          6.74244996         26.28735053
H33                5.88457507          7.48245006         27.02735064
H34                7.36457470          6.74244996         26.28735053
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `[^ ]+`'s ?

Comment: But you are matching the newline before it so it obviously has to be the first column.

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９If we consider all lines will be like what OP has mentioned then yeah that would do ..edited..

Comment: @ heemayl how you manage to select the inverse (I mean select all except this 3 lines). Do you have any idea? something like -v in grep.

Comment: @git That would require a different approach..`-v` won't work as we are matching multilines together whereas `-v` works when we are dealing with single lines..

Answer (score 3):

`gawk -vRS='(^|\n)O[^\n]*\nH[^\n]*\nH[^\n]*' '{print RT}'`

`^` matches the beginning of the file, not the beginning of any line (this may be a dark corner).
`RT` is the text that matched `RS`.
You need GNU Awk for this; standard Awk doesn't allow regex record separators.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk '/^O/ { oline=NR; a=$0; next }
     /^H/ && oline && NR==(oline+1) { hline=NR; a=a RS $0; next }
     /^H/ && hline && NR==(hline+1) {
       print a ORS $0;
       aline=hline=0
}' file

O111               3.82376560          6.83952632         25.21182108
H29                3.45376598          7.57952642         25.95182118
H30                4.93376561          6.83952632         25.21182108
O112               2.46658853          6.91893543         28.05848681
H31                2.09658891          7.65893553         28.79848692
H32                3.57658854          6.91893543         28.05848681
O113               6.25457469          6.74244996         26.28735053
H33                5.88457507          7.48245006         27.02735064
H34                7.36457470          6.74244996         26.28735053
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
{ k = substr($0,1,1) }
(k=="H") && (prevNR["H"]==(NR-1)) && (prevNR["O"]==(NR-2)) {
    print prevRec["O"] ORS prevRec["H"] ORS $0
}
{ prevNR[k]=NR; prevRec[k]=$0 }
' file
O111               3.82376560          6.83952632         25.21182108
H29                3.45376598          7.57952642         25.95182118
H30                4.93376561          6.83952632         25.21182108
O112               2.46658853          6.91893543         28.05848681
H31                2.09658891          7.65893553         28.79848692
H32                3.57658854          6.91893543         28.05848681
O113               6.25457469          6.74244996         26.28735053
H33                5.88457507          7.48245006         27.02735064
H34                7.36457470          6.74244996         26.28735053
```